# "a fact that is already known to the person" or "a fact that is already known by the person"?

Tags: grammar

This video is saying (https://youtu.be/yXJYRlxkfu4?t=46)

> We use ‘as well as’ when we want to add some more information *to* a fact that is already
>   known to the person that we are speaking to.

I am aware that a passive voice is supposed to be followed by "by", in this case, "already known by the person".

The question is "the fact", I am no quite sure the "to" is for the "the fact" or the passive voice, any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/105991/41273

Comment: @Laurel Thank you! Per your link, both of those styles are grammatical and idiomatic, right?

Comment: Yes they are...